# Android: Check if password exists in Databasemanager

Tags: java, android

I want to check if password exists/set by user in Databasemanager before proceeding else.

Get Password string

```
public String getPassword(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query="select * from "+DatabaseManager.TBL_CONFIG;
    Cursor cur=db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if(cur!=null){
        if(cur.moveToNext())
        {

            return cur.getString(0);

        }
    }
    cur.close();
    return null;
}
```

Then I add

```
     if(text.getText().toString().equals(MainActivity.db.getPassword()))
 {
dialog.show();
} else {
dialog.dismiss();
}
```

But it's not working the way I need it.

Comment: You are currently checking if the value in your input field consists of exactly one character, nothing else.

Comment: Can you advise me with a better function please to check from database

Comment: @f1sh please check I've updated the code. Still not working.